# Why doesn't my passing of ID work with httpcontext.session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to pass an ID from one view to another through my controller, but somehow i keep getting the error it cant convert an 'int' to 'Namespace.Modal.name'?

this is the code from my E-mail Model:

```
public int emailID { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Email address")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The email address is required")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[EmailAddress]
public string emailadres { get; set; }
public string omschrijving { get; set; }
public bool verwijderd { get; set; }
public virtual Vrijwilligers vrijwilligerID { get; set; }
```

And here's the code from my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "emailID,emailadres,omschrijving,verwijderd,vrijwilligerID")] Email email)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session["vrijwilligersID"].ToString());
             email.vrijwilligerID = id;
             email.verwijderd = false;
            db.Emails.Add(email);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(email);// vrijwilligers details
    }
```

The error comes from this specific part:

```
int id = int.Parse(HttpContext.Session["vrijwilligersID"].ToString());
email.vrijwilligerID = id;
```

While debugging i found out that the ID is being passed but not correctly.

Comment: Try this, `Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["vrijwilligersID"])`

Comment: I have tried it and it doesnt work, i still get the same error.
`email.vrijwilligersID` doens't accept int value's

Comment: Well vrijwilligerID is of the type `Vrijwilligers` and not `int`, where is the definition for this?

Comment: As @Equalsk said, you need to get the item from db first, like this, `email.vrijwilligerID = db.Vrijwilligers.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);`

Comment: I have a partialview where the emails are showed;

`HttpContext.Session["vrijwilligersID"] = id;
            var aa = db.Emails.Where(e => e.vrijwilligerID.vrijwilligerID == id).ToList();
            return PartialView("Index", aa);`

Comment: @Berkay Thanks! i tried it and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Equalsk pointed that `vrijwilligerID` is not `Int`, it is an `object`, you need to get item from `Vrijwilligers` with that Id, so;

```
email.vrijwilligerID = db.Vrijwilligers.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id == id);
```

Hope helps,